# Implement an event handler in java and pass it to scip via the jni interface

Tags: java, java-native-interface, scip

I use the Scip solver from the Java api, via the Jni interface.

I want to implement an event handler (preferably in java), so that

1. I can get some information about the progress of the solving, that I want to display
2. Be able to interrupt the solving by calling SCIPinterruptSolve(SCIP *scip).

Event handlers are implemented in c and passed to scip via the following native method

```
SCIP_RETCODE SCIPincludeEventhdlrBasic  (   SCIP *  scip,
SCIP_EVENTHDLR **   eventhdlrptr,
const char *    name,
const char *    desc,
SCIP_DECL_EVENTEXEC((*eventexec))   ,
SCIP_EVENTHDLRDATA *    eventhdlrdata 
)
```

Can I implement an event handler in java?

How can I pass an event handler written in java to scip via the jni interface?

Note that there is no method corresponding to SCIPincludeEventhdlrBasic in the jni interface.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with the SCIP JNI interface since it does not support callbacks.